# I am trying to get particular logged in user data in the profile in swift 4

Tags: swift4

I am trying to get a particular logged in ID's data in profile but I am unable to get it I have viewed many links but its not working for me. Below is my function that I have used to get data

**Function**

```
func getCompanyFunc() {
        let empURL = URL(string: "http://172.16.1.22/Get-Company-API/get-companies/")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: empURL!) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if error == nil {
                    self.getCompanyArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([CompanyDataProfile].self, from: data!)

                    for mainArr in self.getCompanyArray {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let companyDefaultValue = UserDefaults.standard
                            if let userID = companyDefaultValue.string(forKey: "user_type_id") {
                                self.getComData = self.getCompanyArray.filter { $0.company_id == userID }
                                print("Company ID Profile=\(userID)")
                                self.companyName_lbl.text = mainArr.company_name
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    print("****Employee Data****\(self.getCompanyArray)")
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Error in get JSON Data Employee\(error)")
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: you get logged in User data from this api?

Comment: I want to get data in the users profile @Kuldeep and with this api i am getting list of users that have registered which i want to fetch a particular user that has logged in only his data should show in his profile\

Comment: I have even tried this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990349/how-to-set-json-output-into-uilabel-in-swift-4-0?rq=1 but with this there is nothing coming in my view and even my array is going nill

Comment: You can load list of users in `UITableView`, once you tapped on any user than you have to pass selected user data in next screen and by using that selected user id, you need to call another api that will return that user data.

Comment: I want this data in the users Profile View (i.e a view controller containing details of the user logged in and not a in tableview)

Comment: what data you get from this api? and add your screen in your question so other can easily help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171815/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-audrey-rozario).

Comment: okay!! @Kuldeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

**UserListObject**

```
import UIKit

class UserListObject: NSObject {

    var strCompanyID: String    = ""
    var strFirstName: String    = ""
    var strLastName: String     = ""
    var strEmail: String        = ""

    class func parseFromDictionary(dict: NSDictionary) -> UserListObject {
        let objUser = UserListObject()

        if let company_id = dict["company_id"] as? String {
            objUser.strCompanyID = company_id
        }
        if let fname = dict["fname"] as? String {
            objUser.strFirstName = fname
        }
        if let lname = dict["lname"] as? String {
            objUser.strLastName = lname
        }
        if let email_id = dict["email_id"] as? String {
            objUser.strEmail = email_id
        }

        return objUser
    }
}
```

**Your ViewController**

Define this globally : `var arrUsers = [UserListObject]()`

so once you get data from API you can store it like below.

```
APIsManager.postCall(url!, params: _parameters, success: { (response) in
    //CommonHelper.hideProgress()
    let JSONData = response as! NSDictionary
    if(JSONData.object(forKey: "Success") as! Bool == true) {
        self.arrUsers.removeAll()
        let arrData = JSONData.value(forKey: "Data") as! NSArray

        for i in 0..<arrData.count {
            let dict = arrData.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary
            let objUser = UserListObject.parseFromDictionary(dict: dict)
            self.arrUsers.append(objUser)
        }
    }
    else {
        // Error
    }
}) { (response) in
    //Error
}
```

Once you get All users in arrUsers than you need to filter like Below.

```
let objLoggedInUser = self.arrUsers.filter{ $0. strCompanyID == YOUR_USERDEFAULT_ID}.first // THAT WILL RETURN YOU WHOLE OBJECT WITH ALL DETAILS
```

Now you can get values like.

```
self.lblFirstName.text = objLoggedInUser. strFirstName
self.lblLastName.text  = objLoggedInUser. strLastName
```